# GroupLayout - components alignment

Tags: java, swing, alignment, layout-manager, grouplayout

I have some issues with the alignment of the components in the groupLayout. 
I want to make a calculator type of Layout with 2 text fields at the top, right below 6 buttons, arranged in 2 columns and 3 lines and a text field for the result but the labels aren't aligned with the text fields and the same goes with the buttons. If you can give some advice, I'd be grateful. Thank you! 
Here's the code:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQBqm.jpg)

```
public class View extends JFrame{

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Example");
    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
    JPanel p3 = new JPanel();
    JPanel p4 = new JPanel();
    JTextField tf = new JTextField(15);
    JTextField tf1 = new JTextField(15);
    JButton b = new JButton(" + ");
    JButton b1 = new JButton(" - ");
    JTextField tf3 = new JTextField(15);

    public View(){
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(p1);
         p1.setLayout(layout);
         layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
         layout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);

         JLabel label = new JLabel("Polinom 1: ");
            JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Polinom 2: ");

        b.setSize(20,20);
        b1.setSize(20,20);

        b.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 50));
        b1.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 50));

         layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                   layout.createSequentialGroup()
                      .addComponent(label)
                      .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                               .addComponent(tf)
                               .addComponent(b))
                      .addComponent(label1)
                      .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                              .addComponent(tf1)
                              .addComponent(b1)

                ));
                layout.setVerticalGroup(
                   layout.createSequentialGroup()
                      .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                           .addComponent(label)
                           .addComponent(tf)
                           .addComponent(label1))
                           .addComponent(tf1)

                      .addComponent(b)
                      .addComponent(b1)
                );

        frame.add(p1);

        JLabel l = new JLabel("Rezultat: ");

        p3.add(b);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(500,400);
        // frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Comment: My main advice is to avoid using GroupLayout to hand-code a Swing GUI. Instead use a much more coder-friendly layout, including nested JPanels each using a simple layout, or the 3rd party MIG layout if your needs are greater.

Comment: 1) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 3) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height. 4) That code both extends `JFrame` & declares an instance of one. Do one or the other, not both.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I'm gonna take them into  consideration!

Comment: 1) Tip: Add @HovercraftFullOfEels (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. 3) Technical point, but they are comments, not answers.